# Using a for loop to set image resources for multiple image views

Tags: java, android, resources, drawable

I am trying to use a for loop to set image resources for several image views. I know the solution i have come up with wont work and i know why. My question is what can i use instead of this? Just to make it clear only some of the images will be updated depending on what the areasArray contains. e.g. 4,7,9 this means only images iv_4, iv_7, iv_9.

```
        iv_0 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_0);
    iv_1 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_1);
    iv_2 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_2);
    iv_3 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_3);
    iv_4 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_4);
    iv_5 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_5);
    iv_6 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_6);
    iv_7 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_7);
    iv_8 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_8);
    iv_9 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_9);
    iv_10 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_10);
    iv_11 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_11);
    iv_12 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_12);
    iv_13 = (ImageView) ViewLameness.findViewById(R.id.iv_13);

    for (int i = 0; i < areasArray.length; i++) {

        int[] images = { R.drawable.f0sc, R.drawable.f1sc, R.drawable.f2sc,
                R.drawable.f3sc, R.drawable.f4sc, R.drawable.f5sc,
                R.drawable.f6sc, R.drawable.f7sc, R.drawable.f8sc,
                R.drawable.f9sc, R.drawable.f10sc, R.drawable.f11sc,
                R.drawable.f12sc, R.drawable.f13sc };

        String image = "iv_" + areasArray[i];

        image.setImageResource(images[i]);

    }
```

Comment: First thing first why is `images`  inside the for loop anyway? And are you sure about this code? image is a `String` not an `ImageView`, how can a `String`have a `setImageResource` method?

Comment: You know it won't work and you know why.. stop doing the _why_.

Comment: I know this code is wrong, i know that a String cant be a ImageView, that's why i'm asking this question. my question is how can i make this work?

Answer (score 3):

This should work..

```
ImageView[] images = new ImageView[] { iv_1, iv_2, ... };
int[] res = new int[] { R.id.iv_1, R.id.iv_2, ... };
int[] drawables = new int[] { R.drawable.f0sc, R.drawable.f1sc, ... };
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res[i]);
    images[i].setImageResource(drawables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply, I didn't no that an array of Imageview could be made. Now i just need to make it so it will only update the images that the areasArray defines, however i should be able to figure that out. thanks jamie

Comment: If I create such an array if `ImageView`s is there anyway by which I could specify their positions? For example: If my layout is relative layout, how would each `ImageView` be placed on the screen?